# Any quick way to find dependency information?

Tags: java, maven

Besides google, is there better way to get dependency information for Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependency:tree`

As described [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/plugin-info.html)

> **dependency:tree**    Displays the dependency tree for this project.

*refer:*
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html